# JOLT Refer mapping value of others array base on "id"

Tags: java, json, jolt

I have a issue JOLT Spec , and i don't know how to resolve it. Please help me to complete this issue.

I have a JSON Input:

```json
{
  "status": [
    {
      "id": "online",
      "state": "valid"
    },
    {
      "id": "busy",
      "state": "unknown"
    },
    {
      "id": "any",
      "state": "unknow",
      "moreInfo": "unavailable"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "title": "foo",
      "availability": [
        "online",
        "busy"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "bar",
      "availability": [
        "busy",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "baz",
      "availability": [
        "any"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And i want to my output like below:

```json
{
  "users": [
    {
      "title": "foo",
      "availability": [
        {
          "id": "online",
          "state": "valid"
        },
        {
          "id": "busy",
          "state": "unknown"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "bar",
      "availability": [
        {
          "id": "busy",
          "state": "unknown"
        },
        {
          "id": "any",
          "state": "unknow",
          "moreInfo": "unavailable"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "baz",
      "availability": [
        {
          "id": "any",
          "state": "unknow",
          "moreInfo": "unavailable"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Mean items of array "users", base on "availability" will refer to "status" array. If items of "availability" same with item's id of "status", will map entire attribute of this item.
Thank you for watching and thinking about my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This spec should do the trick:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "status": {
        "*": {
          "state|moreInfo": "status.@(1,id).&"
        }
      },
      "users": {
        "*": {
          "title": "users[&1].&",
          "availability": {
            "*": "users[&2].&1[&].id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "users": {
        "*": {
          "title": "users[&1].&",
          "availability": {
            "*": {
              "id": {
                "@": "users[&4].&3[&2].&1",
                "*": {
                  "@(6,status.&.state)": "users[&5].&4[&3].state",
                  "@(6,status.&.moreInfo)": "users[&5].&4[&3].moreInfo"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The main idea is to transform the `status` array into a dictionary. To to this, we move the `id` of the status from the array and make it a key.
Check out the [Advanced `@` sign wildcard docs](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L324)
The

```json
"*": {
  "state|moreInfo": "status.@(1,id).&"
}
```

Says:

> for `state` and `moreInfo` keys of the `*` element put them into the `status` object under the key which is a value stored under the `id` key.

Moreover, the first shift operation wraps the elements of the `availability` arrays into a json with `id` key for the corresponding value. The title lands in the same place it is now.

After the 1st "shift" operation:

```json
{
  "status" : {
    "online" : {
      "state" : "valid"
    },
    "busy" : {
      "state" : "unknown"
    },
    "any" : {
      "state" : "unknow",
      "moreInfo" : "unavailable"
    }
  },
  "users" : [ {
    "title" : "foo",
    "availability" : [ {
      "id" : "online"
    }, {
      "id" : "busy"
    } ]
  }, {
    "title" : "bar",
    "availability" : [ {
      "id" : "busy"
    }, {
      "id" : "any"
    } ]
  }, {
    "title" : "baz",
    "availability" : [ {
      "id" : "any"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

In the second shift operation we use the advanced `@` wildcard again.
We leverage the created `status` dictionary and search for the `state` and `moreInfo` under the desired key equal to the `users.availability.id`

Answer (score 1):

You may consider another library *Josson* to do the job by a short expression.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"status\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"id\": \"online\"," +
    "            \"state\": \"valid\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"id\": \"busy\"," +
    "            \"state\": \"unknown\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"id\": \"any\"," +
    "            \"state\": \"unknow\"," +
    "            \"moreInfo\": \"unavailable\"" +
    "        }" +
    "    ]," +
    "    \"users\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"title\": \"foo\"," +
    "            \"availability\": [" +
    "                \"online\"," +
    "                \"busy\"" +
    "            ]" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"title\": \"bar\"," +
    "            \"availability\": [" +
    "                \"busy\"," +
    "                \"any\"" +
    "            ]" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"title\": \"baz\"," +
    "            \"availability\": [" +
    "                \"any\"" +
    "            ]" +
    "        }" +
    "    ]" +
    "}");
```

**Transformation**

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(users.field(availability@.let($id:?).get($.status[id=$id])))");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "users": [
    {
      "title": "foo",
      "availability": [
        {
          "id": "online",
          "state": "valid"
        },
        {
          "id": "busy",
          "state": "unknown"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "bar",
      "availability": [
        {
          "id": "busy",
          "state": "unknown"
        },
        {
          "id": "any",
          "state": "unknow",
          "moreInfo": "unavailable"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "baz",
      "availability": [
        {
          "id": "any",
          "state": "unknow",
          "moreInfo": "unavailable"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```